# Use San Francisco, Helvetica Neue fonts over Arial

Tags: feature-request, design

The current CSS design for Ask Different puts Arial first.

I think we should change this CSS to put San Francisco first, without having to license anything or anything like that. Here is my CSS code:

```
body { font-family: -apple-system, Helvetica Neue, Arial; }
```

The only problem with this is that `-apple-system` is only supported on Apple devices and Safari. However, it can default back to Helvetica Neue.

[*I also created a TamperMonkey script with this same behavior*](https://github.com/Usernamer/AskDifferent-SanFrancisco/blob/master/script.user.js)

Comment: I can't edit this answer due to my score, so I'll just add from my duplicate that Chrome is supported with BlinkMacSystemFont so the font-family directive will be, `font-family: system, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, "Lucida Grande", Arial, sans-serif;`